# Skype is not working on Samsung J5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung

Recently, I have just installed Samsung J5 firmware manually, because there was a problem in updated Marshmallow. Now, whenever I try to use Skype on device it says something went wrong try again later. I tried many times, but still issue is same. My Skype account works well on PC. Before installing firmware, it was working well on J5. But, now I don't know what happened. Have I lost connection with server network forever? I searched on Google but found nothing useful. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have installed Marshmallow firmware. But this time I did it manually. I downloaded firmware from www.sammobile.com web site. Now in new Marshmallow, Skype is working properly. There is no issue at all. Thanks to Sammobile.